# WordPress Iframe for blog image

Tags: plugin-development, images, blog-page

I would like to have an Instagram feed for featured image of the blog.

Already I have Instagram feed blog post but I would like it to be also on featured image.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Link to blog - https://messnermoto.com/blog/

Link to the blog post where you can see Instagram feed which I would like to use as featured image.
- https://messnermoto.com/messnermoto-motorcycle-rearview-mirror-evolution/

[image]

Comment: So you want to use an actual feed instead of the featured image, or you want to be able to use a single instagram photo instead of the featured image? The feed will require you to use the [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) / [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/) and the latter would mean adding a custom field to your post to allow you to enter a URL to a specific instagram post / image.

Comment: Hi, I have already a plugin for feed. My question is how to replace that image that you see on my 1 post with that feed. Thank you!

Comment: You would need to edit your template (or make a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)) and replace the code in `image_frame post-photo-wrapper` with your Instagram feed.

Comment: I have a child theme. Do I need to do for every post or is there a way to fetch it form post? Thank you!

Comment: It depends if you want the same feed for each post, or if you want to load a specific image per post. If you want to load a feed each time, just edit the template file which displays the `image_frame post-photo-wrapper` div class. If you want a custom image, defined on each post (are you using ACF?) then you will need to alter the same div and retrieve the instagram image URL from the post.

Comment: No, I am not using ACF but I can install it if it will make this work.

Comment: To give some more specific info. Every post has its own Instagram feed that is related to that post. This part with Instagram feed is already working. My question is how to replace the featured image on the blog page with specific Instagram feed that you can see on the blog post. You can see Instagram feed if you open one of the posts. Both posts have their own specific feed and future posts will also have specific Instagram feeds.

Comment: OK, so is the feed added as part of the post content, or is it a custom field? You'd still need to edit the template as I have said to load this instagram feed whilst you loop through the posts. If I know how you are adding the instagram feed to your posts, I can attempt a proper answer.

Comment: Hi, I am adding as shortcode that is provided with the plugin ( Instagram Feed by Smash Balloon) . Shortcode looks like this [instagram-feed includewords="#2motorcyclerearviewmirror2" height=auto cols=1]. I am adding it through classic editor.

Comment: OK, so you would need to perhaps add a custom field to specify the `includewords` so that you can pull that out into the loop. You would then use [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) eg `do_sortcode('[instagram-feed includewords="".$include_words.'" height=auto cols=1]');` where `$include_words` is loaded from each post. If you use ACF fields, you can simply create a new "Instragram includewords" text field and then set `$include_words = get_field('includewords');` before calling `do_shortcode`.

Comment: Hi, but where is defined that featured post image will be replaced with the Instagram feed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your theme how to tackle this, because under most circumstances you cannot just change the featured image without writing a plugin.

If you're experienced with writing WordPress plugins (and Instagram' API) you could write your own plugin that replaces the featured image.

I would rather recommend using an existing plugin - the first I googled was [Instagram Feed by Smash Balloon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/), which looks like it can do what you need. Using that plugin I would *not* show the featured image but instead use the Plugin's shortcode in order to show the right Instagram feed for your product.

Comment: Hi, I use that plugin, my question is how to replace that image with it. If you click on the post you can see it already there. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide me with code to replace the featured image with a shortcode?

Comment: This depends on the theme that you use. If you tell me the theme's name I can try to figure out.
The easiest way would be to not show the leading picture (how to achieve that also depends on the theme) and add the instagram feed to the post content using the shortcode.

Comment: Betheme is used on the website. [link](https://themeforest.net/item/betheme-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7758048#item-description__changelog)

Comment: I see. I really can't help with a commercial theme, but if you bought that, you should be able to just ask their support if there's a way of replacing the leading picture by your Instagram feed.